# Understanding GeometricScene

Tags: computational-geometry

I tried to expand a simple geometric scene:

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c  }, {      Triangle[{a, b, c}]}], 1]
```

works fine and shows the triangle.

[image]

But if I try to add a *userdefined*  point, the command doesn't evaluate

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c  }, {Point[ (a + b + c )/3],Triangle[{a, b, c}]}], 1]
```

Also

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c , s }, { s == (a + b + c )/3,   Point[ s],Triangle[{a, b, c}]}], 1]
```

doesn't work.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: `RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c , s }, { s == (a + b + c )/3,   Point[ s],Triangle[{a, b, c}]}], 1]` work in 13.0.1

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my version is 12.2...

Comment: @cvgmt: Your code works in 13.0.0 too.

Comment: On v12.2-Win7x64, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Ngl.png) for the second variation. The first variation works if the Point is actually assigned to a variable that is also present in the variable list for the `GeometricScene`.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for your help, with a fresh kernel now the code works. But if I extend to `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c , s, i, n }, {   s == (a + b + c )/3, 
   i == TriangleCenter [{a, b, c}, "Incenter"], n == 2 s - i, 
   Point[s], Point[i], Point[n], Triangle[{a, b, c}]}], 1]` last point `n` isn't shown. Instead a symbol"+2" appears. Any idea?

Comment: I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijlmD.png) for the extended version.

Comment: @Syed Many thanks. Although the Mathematica versions are the same, we get different results. How can this be?

Comment: Name the geometric scene `gs` and try `FullForm` to see, why `n` went missing. WRI support must be able to say if you are missing an update or if some file has been corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `GeometricScene` is for the hypotheses of the geometry, so `GeometricScene` forwards the second argument to some logical formulas, particularly `MatchQ` (you can have a glimpse of this via `Trace`).

My guess is that, for example, `Triangle[{a,b,c}]`, despite being a non-logical term but a graphics primitive, will be used to logically determine (via `MatchQ`) that `{a,b,c}` forms a triangle in the scene. That being said, `Point[s]` or just `Point` overall doesn't seem to have its counterpart in the `MatchQ`. In fact, I think hypothesizing 'point is point' is redundant, as the points are already given in the first argument `{a,b,c}` and rendered in the scene.

What I'd do instead is

```
RandomInstance@GeometricScene[{a, b, c, s}, {s == (a + b + c)/3, Triangle[{a, b, c}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you .After refreshing my kernel (see my comments with@Syed the code evaluates as expected.